# Add numbers in a string with recursion in Java with substring

Tags: java, recursion, numbers, substring, indexof

I'm trying to add some numbers from a string
For example the string is "5 + 3 +2". This should return 10
This is my code for getting the number of the operator is a "+"

```
        int opIndex= expression.indexOf("+");
        Double lhs = Double.parseDouble(expression.substring(0, opIndex));
        Double rhs = Double.parseDouble(expression.substring(opIndex+1));
```

What I got in return is
lhs = 5 (which is what I wanted)
rhs = returned a string error (3+2);

How can I get number 3 only then do + 2 after the (5+3) or any other approach?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to split the string into a series of operands and operators not just one. Try to look for a tutorial on math expession parsing, there should be plenty on the net.

Comment: `indexOf` has an overloaded version with a beginIndex. Use that in a loop.

Comment: First, there is no `-` character within your string equation therefore `opIndex` will be `-1`. Splitting of the equation needs to be a little more...robust. What you ned is an Math Equation parser.

Comment: If you need to do this recursively, read the first operand and then the operator, then process the remaining string recursively.

Comment: @f1sh that's the part where I got stuck. 
Could you please give me some kind of further explanation or example?

Comment: @NewbieProgrammer222 take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do things recursively with a list of things, always think in the following pattern:

- handle the first element of the list
- handle the rest of the list using a recursive call

So in the case of `"5 + 3 +2"`, split off `5` and `"+"` and then pass the rest (`"3+2"`) to the same method again.

It's also far easier to remove the spaces before you start.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "5 + 3 + 2";
    //remove spaces:
    input = input.replaceAll(" +", "");
    int r = evaluate(input);
    System.out.println(r);
}

private static int evaluate(String s) {
    int operatorIndex = s.indexOf('+');
    if(operatorIndex == -1) {
        //no operator found, s is the last number
        //this is the base case that "ends" the recursion
        return Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
    else {
        //this is left hand side:
        int operand = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, operatorIndex));
        //this performs the actual addition of lhs and whatever rhs might be (here's where recursion comes in)
        return operand + evaluate(s.substring(operatorIndex+1));
    }
}
```

This code prints `10`. It gets a more complex if you also want to support substraction, but you will figure it out.

Comment: Thank you so much.
I can understand the concept of this now.

Comment: Recursion is hard to grasp at first. It seems so clear when you see the solution... You learn the concept over time. You can upvote and/or accept this answer if you like :)

Answer (score 1):

The "RHS" string ends up being something like `"  3 + 2"`. Your job is **not** to get the 3. Your job is to recurse: Give that string to your own algorithm, trust that it works.

That's how recursion works: You assume your algorithm already works, and then you write it, calling yourself, with the additional rule that you can only call yourself with a 'simpler' case (because otherwise it'll never end), *and* that you write code to deal with the simplest case explicitly (which in this case would presumably be if I hand your method just a number. If I hand it `"5"`, it needs to return 5, and not recurse).

Answer (score 0):

you can split the spring using the split method

```
String array[]=expression.split("+")
```

now itrate the aray and you can

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the fact that I cannot use loop. Recursion only.